# Reference PHP Class function method

Tags: php

I have a class:

```
class demo {

      function newDemo(){
          $v=$this->checkDemo;
          $v('hello'); // not working this reference, or how to do this?
      }

      function checkDemo($a){
          ...
          return $a;
      }
           }
```

So, how can i reference checkDemo function method inside class?

Comment: If you call a method checkDemo you need to give brackets (). Second, I don't know what $v('hello') would do, can you give an example?

Comment: @Voitcus looks like the OP's intent is to store a function reference in `$v` then execute the variable function `$v`, which would pass 'hello' to `checkDemo()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski OK, the example above was somewhat confusing for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign it like so:

```
$v = 'checkDemo';
$this->$v('hello');
```

Check out [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) for more examples.

Although I'm not entirely sure *why* you'd do it, that's how.

Answer (score 10):

To make a callable out of an object method, you need an array. Index 0 is the instance, and index 1 is the name of the method:

```
$v = Array($this,"checkDemo");
$v("hello");
```

EDIT: Note that this functionality is only available as of PHP 5.4

Comment: I didn't realize this actually worked! :O  I thought `array($this, 'checkDemo')` only worked with `call_user_func`.

Comment: This only works in PHP 5.4+

Comment: @RocketHazmat Really? I just see "A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1." - I don't see any qualification by version number, unlike other paragraphs in that area, which I assume means it's been that way since OOP was added to PHP.

Comment: @Kolink: I tested it in PHP 5.3 and I get `Fatal error: Function name must be a string`.  http://codepad.viper-7.com/ssQDFb

Comment: All right, fair enough. I guess that should be in the manual somewhere XD Well, ideally developers should keep on top of PHP versions anyway...

Comment: I can't seem to find it in the manual anywhere >.>

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    function Variable()
    {
        $name = 'Bar';
        $this->$name(); // This calls the Bar() method
    }

    function Bar()
    {
        echo "This is Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$funcname = "Variable";
$foo->$funcname();  // This calls $foo->Variable()

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be much easier and simplier if you'd just:

```
class demo {

      function newDemo(){
          echo $this->checkDemo('hello');
      }

      function checkDemo($a){
          return $a;
      }
}

$demo = new demo;

$demo->newDemo(); // directly outputs "hello", either to the browser or to the CLI
```

Answer (score 0):

It's useless when you can call directly $this->checkDemo($data)

However.... you can do as this

```
$v=function($text){ return $this->checkDemo($text); };
echo $v('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`call_user_func`](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function and pass array consist from object reference and method name as first parameter:

```
class demo {

      function newDemo(){
          return call_user_func( array( $this, 'checkDemo' ), 'hello' );
      }

      function checkDemo( $a ){
          ...
          return $a;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this:

```
<?php
class HelloWorld {

    public function sayHelloTo($name) {
        return 'Hello ' . $name;
    }

public function test () {
   $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod(__CLASS__, 'sayHelloTo');
   echo $reflectionMethod->invoke($this, 'Mike');

    }

}

$hello = new HelloWorld();
$hello->test();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php

Answer (score -2):

You must add the arguments when calling a function:

```
$v = $this->checkDemo('hello');
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? He simply asked how to reference a function from within a class.  Nothing complicated like calling a function from a string or object.

Comment: `calling a function from a string or object` is *exactly* what he wanted.

Comment: I stand corrected, but that is not what he asked: `reference checkDemo function method inside class`.

Comment: His example code shows what he wants, he just didn't word the question properly.